# Change a property in an ItemUpdated event receiver

Tags: event-receivers, splistitem

I have a very simple code but I can't change a property in an `ItemUpdated` event receiver

```
  public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties  properties)
  {
       base.ItemUpdated(properties);
       using(DisabledEventsScope scope = new DisabledEventsScope())
       {
           SPListItem listItem = properties.ListItem;
           listItem["Title"] = "A cool new title!";
           listItem.Update();
       }
  }
```

it doesn't throw any errors but the property is not being updated.

Answer (score 0):

I would first check if your Event Receiver is attached to the list.

It's easy to view all attached Event Receivers with PowerShell:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb <Url>
$list = $web.Lists["<ListName>"]  
$list.EventReceivers
```